# Localization of a wordpress theme without a textdomain

Tags: wordpress, localization, themes

I have a wordpress theme without textdomain (i.e. e(x) and not e(x,domain)). I also have the .po and .mo files in a folder under /themes/My Theme/localization (Notice the space name in the my theme). I would like to activate fr_FR. I created fr_FR.po and .mo and changed the wp-config to add the locale for fr_FR. However, I am still not getting the french to work. I saw many sites telling you to add a load_theme_textdomain at the top of functions.php, but I do not know what would my textdomain be. Any help will be appreciated.

Youssef

Answer (score 6):

To get theme localization working, you're going to need to go through your theme and add a domain to every `_e()` and `__()` function call.  this:

```
_e('some text');
__('some other text');
```

Will have to become this:

```
_e('some text', 'your-domain');
__('some other text', 'your-domain');
```

Next you'll need to add this bit of code at the top of your functions.php file:

```
load_theme_textdomain( 'your-domain', TEMPLATEPATH.'/localization' );

$locale = get_locale();
$locale_file = TEMPLATEPATH."/localization/$locale.php";
if (is_readable($locale_file))
    require_once($locale_file);
```

You can read more about it [in this post](http://www.zyblog.de/2006/01/15/localizing-wordpress-themes/2/).

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. Before I do it the way you recommend, I would like to hear from the rest of the community to confirm that there is no easy way.  :(

Comment: @user404057 you also need to actually translate the po file . read here :http://codex.wordpress.org/Translating_WordPress

Answer (score 5):

Add your own text domain. I did this recently to a theme which was not designed for localization, so I'm posting what I did.

Add this to functions.php

`load_theme_textdomain( 'your-domain', TEMPLATEPATH.'/languages' );`

where `your-domain` can be any name, but keep it uniform throughout all theme files.

Now go through all the theme PHP files, and do the following:

If you see `_e('some text')` then change it to `_e('some text', 'your-domain');`

If you see `__('some text')` then change it to `__('some text', 'your-domain');`

If you see `"some text"` without `__()` or `_e()` then,

If `"some text"` is used in a function call, then make it `__()` like above, including the text domain

If `"some text"` is just printed and not part of any function call, surrround it with a `_e()` like shown above, and don't forget the text domain.

Read the [Wordpress internationalization and localization guide](http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers) for more information.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I felt this should be answered anyway, considering the trouble I went through to find this :|

Answer (score 0):

After an unbelievably long string of forums going through the same steps of how to set it up when everything is working correctly, I finally found what was causing the issue for me.

If the server sets the global `$locale` before wordpress has a bash at it, then wordpress uses the server's locale settings (in the `wp-includes/l10n.php` file, the function `get_locale`).

The solution I used, is to set the global $locale right next to defining `WPLANG`...

```
global $locale;
$locale = 'am_AM';
define('WPLANG', $locale);
```